# StopWatch and Timer Accuracy

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm using the following code to control a label to output a stopwatch. The buttons work, and the label is outputting the information mostly correctly, however it only update every so often and i would like for the label to update the information every millisecond.

```
Private SW As New Stopwatch
    Dim timercount As Integer = 1 'The number of seconds 

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        SW.Start()
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Timer1.Enabled = False 'Stop the timer
        timercount = 0 'Reset to 0 seconds
        Label10.Text = "00:00:00.000"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim ts As TimeSpan = SW.Elapsed
        Label10.Text = ts.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss\.fff")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Timer1.enabled = False
    End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: _Every millisecond_ ? So what interval are you setting on your timer?  See the remarks section in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=windowsdesktop-5.0

Comment: Does your monitor have a refresh rate of 1000 Hz? It would be more reasonable to update the displayed value at perhaps 30 times per second, but show the value to the nearest millisecond.

Comment: 30 times per second is probably fine, but right now it seems like it is skipping seconds being shown. it goes from "00:00:00.000" to "00:00:00.986" to"00:00:01.199", so it isn't showing at least every second that passes.

Comment: Twice per second is probably fine, and will make your app _way_ better for resource use...

Comment: Note that you will be subject to the Windows timer resolution; the default resolution is between 15 and 16 ms.  You can read more about the rules on the timer resolution in a blog post by Bruce Dawson here: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2020/10/04/windows-timer-resolution-the-great-rule-change/

Comment: Ultimately, Windows is not a real-time OS, so you will never get the degree of consistency that you seem to be hoping for.  Timer ticks are guaranteed to occur on *at least* the specified interval, not *exactly* the specified interval.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the timer to a reasonable value, say 20 times a second, to rapidly display it changing.

You can create the timer and stopwatch in code, which I think is easier than adding a control to the form—you can see right there in the code what is being programmed. I used sensible names for the buttons so that you can tell what is meant to do what.

If you keep the sub to display the data separate from the code that processes the data, it is easy to change the display in just one place, in case someone decided they wanted it written as words, for example, or maybe the hours in a separate box, or something.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch
    Dim tim As Timer

    Private Sub ShowElapsedTime()
        lblTime.Text = sw.Elapsed.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss\.fff")

    End Sub

    Private Sub bnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bnStart.Click
        sw.Restart()
        tim.Enabled = True

    End Sub

    Private Sub bnStop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bnStop.Click
        sw.Stop()
        tim.Enabled = False
        ShowElapsedTime()

    End Sub

    Private Sub bnReset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bnReset.Click
        tim.Enabled = False
        sw.Reset()
        ShowElapsedTime()

    End Sub

    Private Sub tim_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        ShowElapsedTime()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        tim = New Timer With {.Interval = 50}
        AddHandler tim.Tick, AddressOf tim_Tick
        ShowElapsedTime()

    End Sub

End Class
```